# Graphics card or mainboard defect?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express, post

My PC has the following specs:

- eVGA Z68 FTW Mainboard
- AMD Radeon HD 7970 Graphics Card

I am having the following problem:

My PC had a White Screen yesterday (the whole Screen turned White while usage and I had to shut it down forcefully). I started it up again and some time later I had a black Screen - same Problem just in black.

But then it would not start and POST again. When I powered it up, the fans started running but I could not hear the POST-beep. So I opened my PC up and looked on the debug-code on the Mainboard:

[image]

I turned it blue so you can see it a little bit better. Im not sure if it says

- **b2**: Legacy Option ROM Initialization

or

- **62**: Installation of the South Bridge Runtime Services

The strange thing now is that when I Switch the PCI-E port to any other port, the POST starts and beeps 5 times, showing the Code **d6**: "No Console Output Devices are found". I have also tried reseting the CMOS after switching the Slot, does not work either.

So now my question is: Is my graphics Cards damaged or are the Slots on the Mainboard damaged? Or am I maybe not reseting the Cmos correctly after switching the Slot?

**UPDATE**: I tried another BIOS (changed the switch) and now I get Code **99**: Super IO Initialization

Comment: The code is a b not a 6.  Does your motherboard have a dual bios feature, if so, there should be a button you can pressed to load the backup firmware.

Comment: Yes there is a switch with three Positions. I already tried all three positions but it does not Change anything. The Problem is how can I Flash it when I don't have any Access to my PC?

Comment: I updated my original post.

Answer (score -1):

The debug code is b2. It sounds like possibly a bios issue. Do you have another computer in which you can download the latest bios revision and flash it?

Comment: Yes I could try that.

Comment: If you have another computer to obtain the bios rom for your motherboard, most high end motherboards will flash directly in the bios with the rom on usb flash drive.

Comment: I tried falsing it with the newest Version some time ago and it told me "No PDR Region"

Comment: No pdr means a file (the pdr file) was missing. Also, 99 should be a functioning state. b2 should be a functioning state but there could be bios corruption.